# Properly typing callback functions in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to properly type a callback function. I distilled my use case to this:

```
const func = <Args extends any[]>(
  args: Args,
  callback: (...args: Args) => void
) => callback(...args);

func([1, true], (a0, a1) => {
  console.log(a0, a1);
});
```

I want the type of `a0` to be number and the type of `a1` to be boolean however i am getting both `a0`, and `a1` as number | boolean

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD3Ah.png)

any idea how to resolve this?

```
const func = <Args extends any[]>(
  args: Args,
  callback: (...args: Args) => void
) => callback(...args);

func([1, true], (a0, a1) => {
  console.log(a0, a1);
});
```

I want the type of a0 to be number and the type of a1 to be boolean however i am getting both a0, and a1 as number | boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the default behavior of the compiler with the non-primitive types. It widens the type for arrays and objects, which is totally okay to make working with them easier:

```
// string[] not ['str']
const arr = ['str']

// {name: string} not {name: 'str'}
const obj = {
   name: 'str'
}
```

However, in some cases it is not what we want:

```
// (number | boolean)[]
const arr = [1, true]
```

To make it actually `[1, true]` we have two options:

1. [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):
   `const assertion` prevents the compiler from widening the type of the variable and makes it readonly:

```
// readonly [1, true]
const arr = [1, true] as const
```

If we try to pass the `[1, true]` to the func, we will get the error:

```
Argument of type 'readonly [1, true]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.
  The type 'readonly [1, true]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'any[]'
```

The issue in here is that readonly arrays are not assignable to mutable arrays, since readonly arrays are *supersets* for the mutable arrays:

```
// false
type Case1 = readonly any[] extends any[] ? true : false
// true
type Case2 = any[] extends readonly any[] ? true : false
```

So, we need to update the constraints in the `func`:

```
const func = <Args extends readonly any[]>(
  args: Args,
  callback: (...args: Readonly<Args>) => void,
) => callback(...args);
```

Testing:

```
func([1, true] as const, (a0, a1) => {
  console.log(a0, a1); // a0: 1, a1: true
});
```

1. [const type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) **Typescript >= 5.0**:
   Const type parameters allow us to do the same thing that *const assertion* does. So if we pass literal object/array to the function it won't be widened:

```
const func = <const Args extends readonly any[]>(
  args: Args,
  callback: (...args: Readonly<Args>) => void,
) => callback(...args);

func([1, true], (a0, a1) => {
  console.log(a0, a1); // a0: 1, a1: true
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAeAggJwOYQwCmAHlEWACaE5ECGl4ANgJ4x1gsDaAugHwAKAFAx2+CAC4YuAgBoRMYHSZMARnWABrKQIB0+uuKkAleozCts4vgEo0fGADcQAS0ry7qB0pXqteg3EbAG4hIURkAS4ARlkYKBwEIh52QlBIKDiBOgAGOLpozwcAbwV0iBAmIl0mEDxsvPZC4JgAelb2HKlYpqkEpKEAXxCwsDoAWyIIAAcNIhgAdXBKIhw4Jgn50tFy2AiUdAxd6XFiMgpqGFoGZjYObn5hUVFDAikZCHlnxWU1DW0YAFdK9JDBTDcLCwrARbPYnK53Aoij9fP8gSCRgp9lEev1kllcvlCnDts9ypVqrV6oSmiE2h1ct0iX1EkQFMNQoMhEA)

Comment: const type parameter is what I was looking for. the `as const` solves it but then the user of my function will have to put it for the typing to work. the second one it just works. We are on typescript 4.9 though so we need to update before. but thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Type inference isn't helping you here as array are always infered as unions (`(number|boolean)[]`)not tuples (`[number, boolean]`).

The type assertion to a tuple fixes your issue:

```
func([1, true] as [number, boolean], (a0, a1) => {
  console.log(a0, a1);
});
```